# Convert oracle date string to SQL Server datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime

In a SQL Server 2000 DB, I have a table which holds string representations of Oracle DB dates. They are formatted like "16-MAY-12". I need to convert these to datetime. I can not seem to find a conversion style number that matches, nor can I find a function that will allow me to specify the input format. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting an error message? If so, what is it? What are your regional / language settings? Also, what does September 18th look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '16-MAY-12');
```

You can also try using [`TO_CHAR()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php) to convert the Oracle values to a more SQL Server-friendly format (best is `YYYYMMDD`) before pulling them out of the darker side.

Comment: The convert did not work for me. Syntax error 241. I gave up on the SQL Server end and took your suggestion to extract the date from Oracle in a friendlier format. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You probably have other dates that don't look quite like above. Or, the SQL Server side has regional / language settings that make the format less acceptable (this is why I asked about these earlier).

Comment: For posterity's sake, this is the syntax for Oracle to output in ISO format: `TO_CHAR(DateField, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow Aaron's advice and cast to string on the Oracle side and then did a check/recast on the MS SQL side.  See example below:

---

```
    ;WITH SOURCE AS (
    SELECT * FROM openquery(lnk, 
    'SELECT
        TO_CHAR(OFFDATE , ''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'') AS OFFDATE,
    FROM
        ORACLE_SOURCE')),
    SOURCE_TRANSFORM AS
    (
    SELECT
        CASE 
        WHEN ISDATE(OFFDATE) = 1 THEN CAST(OFFDATE AS DATETIME)
        ELSE NULL END AS OFFDATE
    FROM
        SOURCE
    )
    SELECT * FROM SOURCE_TRANSFORM
```